# EEVEE bake indirect lighting for an animation

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, lightprobe

I am rendering an animation in EEVEE and I want the indirect lighting to be baked for every frame. This is because I want the scene to be lit up **during** the animation, and not preset.

The first frame: [image]

I want the animation to start so, and the last frame: 
[image]

In both of these screenshots, I have baked the indirect lighting individually. One overwrites the other.
Is there any wayto transition from one lighting condition to another, as shown below?

Comment: Baking is pre-calculations saved in a buffer. Assume that is takes 10Mb for a simple frame. If you have an animation of 100 frame it takes 1Gb of memory (or file saved). Not to mention the time spent on calculation to create those. At some point it's not worth it. Maybe it's like that for those reasons.

Comment: Assuming there were a option to re-bake the cubemaps on each rendered frame it would require the same amount of memory for each frame, but would simply recalculate the cache for each render, @4E71-NOP where are you getting 1Gb from? A simple python script could very easily solve this, and a even better solution would be for Blender devs to add this as a option so custom script is not necessary .

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would render twice with the baked lighting different each render and then do some kind of fade or dissolve between the two. Should approximate a light change.

Comment: Could you expand on how to do this? Perhaps show some screenshots or animation of the results

Comment: Not on my main system right now to do that, but it you bake the lighting on the whole scene with one light, render the full shot, then change the lighting or duplicate the blend file for the second version render the full shot. Open both video clips and cross fade them so the main elements will be the same but the lighting should be the only thing that changes. I do most of that sort of thing in post using after effects but blenders video editor. Then just change the speed of the cross fade between the to versions. That would I think get roughly the result you're looking for.

Comment: You should include that in your answer, once you reach your system. Don't post it in the comments where it is easy to miss